# Larvel 9 Vite long build time

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, vuetifyjs3

I have a very basic Laravel 9 project using Vue 3 and Vuetify 3 and for some reason it takes about 30 minutes to run the npm run build command, meanwhile npm run dev only takes a few seconds to start up. I have searched google and there seems to be nothing on this topic so I figured I would ask it here. I don't even know where to begin to start troubleshooting because like I said its a very basic app at the moment and I'm tempted to just start a whole new project seeing that it is still in it's early stages but I would prefer not to start over. Below is my vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

below is app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

// Default Scaffolding
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import {InertiaProgress} from '@inertiajs/progress';
import {resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import {ZiggyVue} from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import {createVuetify} from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import {aliases, fa} from 'vuetify/iconsets/fa-svg'

// Font Awesome
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {faEnvelope, faKey, faBars, faMoneyBillTrendUp} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all'

library.add(faEnvelope, faKey, faBars, faMoneyBillTrendUp)

//Layouts
import AuthLayout from './Layouts/AuthLayout.vue'

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// DATEPICKER
import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                dark: false,
                colors: {
                    primary: '#43A047', // #E53935
                    danger: colors.red.base
                }
            },
        },
    },
    icons: {
        defaultSet: 'fa',
        aliases,
        sets: {
            fa,
        },
    },
})


import Vue3EasyDataTable from 'vue3-easy-data-table';
import 'vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css';
//
// const app = createApp(App);


createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    // resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    resolve: name => {
        const page = resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
        page.then((module) => {
            module.default.layout = module.default.layout || AuthLayout;
        });
        return page;
    },
    setup({el, app, props, plugin}) {
        return createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
            .use(plugin)
            .use(vuetify)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
            .component('Datepicker', Datepicker)
            .component('EasyDataTable', Vue3EasyDataTable)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({color: '#4B5563'});
```

If anything else is needed please let me know. I really don't want to be waiting 30 minutes for this to compile every time I update the app

The main goal is to cutting the build time down to a reasonable duration

Edit: When running npm run build, it hangs on a single step for about 10-30 seconds depending on the step. Step Example: transforming (856) node_modules/function-bind/implementation.js

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?